# Flatten nested JSON retrieved from website and write to CSV in Python 3

Tags: python, json, api, csv

We want to get data from IMF website and dump it into a csv file. Getting the data is done using the API published by IMF for this purpose. However the retrieved json list contains a nested dictionary that may be empty or have varying number of elements depending upon the years for which data is not null. 
Below is a snippet, created to pinpoint the issue. We are using python 3.6.5 through jupyter notebook

We have tried using json_normalize but it is only able to convert the top level to csv. The second element of the JSON contains a nested dictionary and this causes the undesired output.

```
import requests
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
#url = 'http://dataservices.imf.org/REST/SDMX_JSON.svc/CompactData/IFS/A.AU..?startPeriod=2017&endPeriod=2019'
url = 'http://dataservices.imf.org/REST/SDMX_JSON.svc/CompactData/IFS/A.AU.FDSBT_XDC+GG_GEG_G01_XDC+FFSE_XDC.?startPeriod=2017&endPeriod=2019'
# Navigate to series in API-returned JSON data
json_raw = (requests.get(f'{url}').json()['CompactData']['DataSet']['Series'])

json_normalize(json_raw)
```

json_normalize results in the output as (observe that 'Obs' containing nested dictionary array is causing the issue)

```
  @FREQ      @INDICATOR @REF_AREA @TIME_FORMAT @UNIT_MULT                                                                                              Obs  Obs.@OBS_VALUE Obs.@TIME_PERIOD
0     A        FFSE_XDC        AU          P1Y          6                                                                                              NaN  15750.23064215             2017
1     A  GG_GEG_G01_XDC        AU          P1Y          6  [{'@TIME_PERIOD': '2017', '@OBS_VALUE': '4168'}, {'@TIME_PERIOD': '2018', '@OBS_VALUE': '3443'}]            NaN              NaN
2     A       FDSBT_XDC        AU          P1Y          6                                                                                              NaN             NaN              NaN
```

We want a result as below so that we can dump in structured format to csv

```
  @FREQ      @INDICATOR @REF_AREA @TIME_FORMAT @UNIT_MULT Obs.@OBS_VALUE_0 Obs.@TIME_PERIOD_0 Obs.@OBS_VALUE_1 Obs.@TIME_PERIOD_1
0     A        FFSE_XDC        AU          P1Y          6 15750.23064215                 2017              NaN                NaN
1     A  GG_GEG_G01_XDC        AU          P1Y          6 4168                           2017 3443                           2018
2     A       FDSBT_XDC        AU          P1Y          6              NaN                NaN              NaN                NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

This may help

```
def get_details_in_csv(jsonData):
    csvio = io.StringIO()
    names = ['Account Number', 'Account Name', 'Region', 'SG', 'Inbound port', 'Inbound IP', 'Assessment']
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvio, fieldnames=names)
    writer.writeheader()
    for security_group in jsonData['SecurityGroups']:
        groupId = security_group["GroupId"]
        for inboundEntry in security_group["InboundDetails"]:
            inboundPort = inboundEntry['port']
            inboundIP = inboundEntry['source']
            assessment = inboundEntry['assessment']
            writer.writerow({'Account Number': ACCOUNT_NUMBER, 'Account Name': ACCOUNT_NAME, 'Region': REGION,
                             'SG': groupId, 'Inbound port': inboundPort,
                             'Inbound IP': inboundIP, 'Assessment': assessment})

    response = csvio.getvalue()
    print(csvio.getvalue())
    csvio.close()
    return response
```